# Get dataset Item on Condition using c#

Tags: c#, dataset

I have a dataset as :

```
itemname |categoryname
------------------
item1    | category1
item2    | category1
item3    | category4
item4    | category5
item5    | category1
```

I want to get the category name for an item.

Comment: You can get it from the `categoryname` column, of course.  What have you tried and in what way is that attempt not working?  It's not clear at all what the issue is here.

Answer (score 0):

You can either set the filter property of your datatable or use a linq query or loop through all the rows until you find the one containing the wanted item.